# JS not picking up click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

My aim is to generate a Google Analytics event when a user clicks on a "sign up" link or button. I have the following code:

```
<script>
JQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $( ".menu-item" ).click(function() {
    ga('send', 'event', 'link', 'click', 'Sign Up link');
  });
  $( ".et_pb_more_button" ).click(function() {
    ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'Sign Up button');
  });
});
</script>
```

I've tried it with and without the `JQuery(document).ready(function(`), replaced the `ga()` function with just a plain `alert()`, but the problem seems to be that the site (WordPress based) isn't recognising the JQuery.

Any suggestions on how I could make this work, please?

Comment: Any errors in the console? Are the `.menu-item` and `.et_pb_more_button` elements in the DOM on page load, or are they added later dynamically?

Comment: You've to use `JQuery` or `$` not the both...

Comment: Shouldn’t that be `jQuery` instead of `JQuery`?

Comment: Without the jQuery / JQuery it gives an error saying the $ is not a recognised function. With the jQuery in there, it only gives this error, which i don't think is related: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause().

Comment: I tried 'jQuery' and 'JQuery', and it doesn't work with either. Elsewhere on the page a developer used 'JQuery', so I went with that. Does it make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace JQuery(document) with $(document) this will work

put this code right after include jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( ".menu-item" ).click(function() {
    ga('send', 'event', 'link', 'click', 'Sign Up link');
  });
  $( ".et_pb_more_button" ).click(function() {
    ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'Sign Up button');
  });
});
```

Comment: @FarhadD try this one

Comment: @FarhadD comment "ga()" method that is called inside onclick event. just put alert('Some Text') and than check, may there is an error in side "ga()". and also make it sure that there is an "menu-item" class with that element.

Comment: Still no luck. It's like it just doesn't recognise the function. The element is definitely there <li id="menu-item-424" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-424"><a href="/#form">Sign Up Now</a></li>

Comment: Did you Replace "JQuery" with "$"?  and also check error log in console.

Comment: Yes - tried both and neither worked. No errors in console

Comment: Try this what happen? $(document).ready(function() {
  $( ".menu-item" ).click(function() {
    alert('menu-item clicked');
  });
  $( ".et_pb_more_button" ).click(function() {
    alert('et_pb_more_button clicked');
  });
});

Comment: Didn't work. It's definitely an issue with the jQuery not executing. And I need to figure out why that's happening even though there is a call to includ jQuery v1.12.4 before the script.

Comment: Finally.. put this before your script loading  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
<input type='button' onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'link', 'click', 'Sign Up link');" 
value="Sign Up">
```

This is pure way to call up your ga code, if there is.

I hope this will help.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't an option with the particular theme the website's using. Also, a lot of members on here advise against such an implementation of onClick

Comment: But anyway, you can include jquery plugin like this in your wordpress theme [here](https://digwp.com/2009/06/including-jquery-in-wordpress-the-right-way/)

Comment: @Swapper, yes you are right he can use jquery pulgin or can bind using HTML onclick attribute.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer**

Its word press, you need to include jquery.

Add `wp_enqueue_script('jquery');` before you enqueue your scripts.

```
wp_enqueue_script( string $handle, string $src = '', 
array $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, bool $in_footer = false )
```

Refer [wordpress developer](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) site for details

**Old Answer**

If the script is being loaded in the footer we can wrap the code in an anonymous function where we pass in jQuery to be mapped to $.

```
(function($) {
     $( ".menu-item" ).click(function() {
       ga('send', 'event', 'link', 'click', 'Sign Up link');
     });
    $( ".et_pb_more_button" ).click(function() {
      ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'Sign Up button');
    });

})( jQuery );
```

If you absolutely need to load the scripts in the header, you'll probably need to use a document ready function anyway, so you can just pass in $ there.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

   // $ Works! You can test it with next line if you like

});
```

Comment: That didn't work either. Could it be a problem with JQuery versions?

Comment: Is $( ".menu-item" ).click(function() {alert(1);}); works, please check? we are checking is jQuery working.

Comment: Its word press, you need to include jquery. Add wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); before you enqueue your scripts.

Comment: add more details on this on answer, there is a way to use jquery on word press, refer https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: Tried it but the wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); did nothing :(

Comment: Made it work by hard-calling jQuery with the <script> tag, as suggested by Faraz. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Try with triggerHandler to force click event:

```
$( ".menu-item" ).click(function() {
       ga('send', 'event', 'link', 'click', 'Sign Up link');
}).triggerHandler('click');
```